# Set parameter from voltage output (LTspice)

Tags: ltspice, spice

I have PULSE(0 123 0 0.0000001 0.0000001 0.0000333 0.0000666) and I want to change the sixth parameter according to a voltage source output. I need to alter the parameter to make sine wave.

How could I do that?

I would imagine something like PULSE(0 123 0 0.0000001 0.0000001 V1+0.0000333 0.0000666)

TV1 is SINE(0 0.0000333 50 0)

Comment: Just add two voltage sources, one a `PULSE` the other a `SINE`. Neither of those accepts time dependent variables as parameters, but they can accept `.param`.

Comment: but can .param be time dependant? i simply need to change pulse value to simulate sine wave with pwm

Answer (score 2):

All `.param` statements are evaluated prior to simulation start, therefore `time`, which starts at zero with the simulation, cannot be a parameter. A `.func` can be time dependent, but then its evaluation will only be done *during* the simulation. Implicitly, if the `PULSE` and the `SINE` sources can accept `.param` but not `time`-dependent `.func` definitions then they can't have variable parameters.

However, put like that it's an XY problem. What you describe is a PWM, since you need to vary the 6th term (`Ton`) in a `PULSE`, according to a `SINE`. For that, there already are [solutions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/367832/95619).

Comment: I tried that example in link. How is it supposed to change that pulse parameter? How could I apply it to mine?

Comment: @RiDi You'll have to think for yourself a bit, otherwise how do you expect to get on in life with problems: by asking at every step? What is depicted in the linked answer is the basic configuration for generating a [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation). If it's that difficult, [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/372170/95619) is a practical example.

Comment: your example give [this](https://ibb.co/yQV4s6Y) result - shouldnt PWM be like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/PWM%2C_3-level.svg)?

Comment: @RiDi It looks like you used a fixed voltage for the reference, not a sine. Either that or you didn't run it for a long enough time span. There is a third possibility: that you don't know what PWM means or does, but surely this is not the case, no?

Comment: sorry, I mean it is not pwm on switches, but their control signals. I do not understand why they (switches) should be controlled like this

Comment: @RiDi That would depend on the context and, as such, deserves a new question. When you do ask again, though, be sure to ask what you *need*, not what you *think* you need, along with a context and -- preferably -- schematics to show exactly what/who/where. This is needed to avoid people trying to guess and, instead, give a precise answer (this being a Q&A site, not a forum).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128826/discussion-between-ri-di-and-a-concerned-citizen).

Comment: also - why is current smooth (sine). but voltage not?